# How to keep track of connections/clients in EventMachine?

Tags: ruby, websocket, eventmachine

I'm using [websocket-eventmachine-server](https://github.com/imanel/websocket-eventmachine-server) to create a websocket server.

What I'd like to do is create an android app that allows people to have many 1 on 1 conversations with each other. That means each person will need to subscribe to a bunch of chatrooms that they are having a 1 on 1 conversation in.

All the examples online seem to provide echo servers which message everyone. That's obviously not what I'm going for, so I was wondering how to keep track of individuals to send them direct messages?

In the gem [em-websocket](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket), in the `onopen` method, there was a return variable for the handshake, which would be able to obtain query fields from the uri. See below sample code I wrote. I could see myself using that query to get the connection, to send a direct message. The problem is, em-websocket is obsolete now and websocket-eventmachine-server doesn't provide a handshake return variable in `onopen`.

What's the proper way to create a 1 on 1 messaging system with many users with the `websocket-eventmachine-server`? If I'm supposed to track clients, how do I go about doing that?

```
clients = {}
EventMachine::WebSocket.run(host: '0.0.0.0', port: '8080') do |ws|
    ws.onopen { |handshake|
        query = handshake.query # in client side I pass an id field so I know who connected
        clients['query'] = ws
    }

    ws.onmessage{|msg_in_json|
        params = JSON.parse(msg_in_json)
        clients[params['recipient']].send params['message'] 
    }
```

Comment: See if this help you in any sort [`link`](https://github.com/amardaxini/em-websocket-chat-demo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at this example from the `EventMachine` repository: [EventMachine Repo](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/master/examples/guides/getting_started/03_simple_chat_server.rb).

The gist of it is you can use a constant variable (denoted with `@@`) to track clients as they connect. A connection attempt is made in the `post_init` method of the `EM::Connection` class. If the connection is successful, `EM::Connection` will call `connection_completed`. If the connection is unsuccessful, `unbind` will be called (great for clean up).

If you store connected clients in an array using some unique identifier, it's trivial to look the client up and then use the `send_data` method to send stuff to that client.